# mongodb aggregate division between to arrays last elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a feed with products that I store in a db (so Im not in control over the structure of the data or its properties). The feed is stored in a mongoDB and accessible later on a website. This is example of the data stored in db.

```
  {
    productName: 'ABC',
    price: {
      previous: [null, null, 100],
      latest: [200, 200, 200],
    },
  };
```

On the site I want to list products in order of largest discount. I.e price.latest / price.previous. I've tried alot and I want to do something like this:

```
         $set: {
              discount: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $and: [
                      { $gt: [{ $last: '$price.latest' }, null] },
                      { $gt: [{ $last: '$price.previous' }, null] },
                    ],
                  },
                  then: {
                    $divide: [
                      { $last: '$price.latest' },
                      { $last: '$price.previous' },
                    ],
                  },
                  else: null,
                },
              },
          }
```

I cant get it to work and I dont know if its the null check of division crashes. :/

Comment: You will probably need checks to see if the arrays are existing or null and if the last value is zero or null. `$ifNull` is useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct as can be seen [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qoTPfHjxxfd), the only edge case you left out is the case that `price.previous` is equal to 0. This was an easy fix as you just have to change the `null` to `0` in your `$gt` conditions:

```
{
  $set: {
    discount: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $and: [
            {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $last: "$price.latest"
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $last: "$price.previous"
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        then: {
          $divide: [
            {
              $last: "$price.latest"
            },
            {
              $last: "$price.previous"
            }
          ]
        },
        else: null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qoTPfHjxxfd)